# Python: Using an if loop in a while loop

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a meme generator (I know random idea but it's for a Twitch streamer) and I want to be able to make my input loop so I can keep asking for a meme input. My code looks like this:

```python
import time

print("Hey guys this is Alex from Protostar here.")
time.sleep(2)
print("And welcome to the Protostar random meme generator!")
time.sleep(2)
print("This is made by the cheeky scrub known as @dylan_purser on twitter and twitch lol xD")
time.sleep(2)
print("He tries to make memes but does a shit job of them lol still check me out on soundcloud: @dylanpursermusic LUL")
time.sleep(4)
print("Are you ready then?")
time.sleep(2)
print("Lets load the program, BUDDY!!!")
time.sleep(2)

memecount = 0

print("Current memes coded: Dank Memes, Chrissy, WOO, Start, Mate, Skrillex, DAW")
print("PLEASE USE SAME CAPITALISATION AS THE MEMES LIST!")

meme = input("What danke memes do you want?")

while True:
    if meme == "Dank Memes":
        print("danke mem ays man")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "Chrissy":
        print("Chrissy just like died... RIP Chrissy.exe")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "WOO":
        print("WOOOH")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("WOOOO")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("WOOOOOO")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "Start":
        print("Start right off with a f*cking meme")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "Mate":
        print("ALRIGHT MATE!")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "Skrillex":
        print("I AM SKRILLEX")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "DAW":
        print("Because I use Reason")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("What software do I use? Read the fucking info mate!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("You ever heard of a de-esser mate?")
        time.sleep(1)
```

(the code wont run btw)

When I run it it just loops the if/elif command (so for example it just keeps on printing "danke mem ays man" when I input "Dank Memes".

Has anyone got a solution to my problem?

Comment: You're only asking for input once before you enter the loop, so it will always be the same

Comment: so should I move the loop before the input then?

Comment: Your loop goes forever, and since the first `if` condition is met, it will never proceed to check the `elif` one, and as it just keeps going forever, the input meets the condition, well, forever, since it isn't altered.

Comment: @dylanpurser No, because then meme won't have been set when the loop runs. If you want to ask for input once per loop, when do you think you should move it?

Comment: Put `meme` inside the `while` loop; also add a condition to `break` out of the loop

Comment: add 'meme = input("What danke memes do you want?")' just below your 'while true'

Answer (score 1):

The input needs to be nested inside the while loop, otherwise, the loop will keep going forever on the same input, since it's a `while True`

Try:

```
while True:
    meme = input("What danke memes do you want?")
    if meme == "Dank Memes":
        print("danke mem ays man")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "Chrissy":
        print("Chrissy just like died... RIP Chrissy.exe")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "WOO":
        print("WOOOH")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("WOOOO")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print("WOOOOOO")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "Start":
        print("Start right off with a f*cking meme")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "Mate":
        print("ALRIGHT MATE!")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "Skrillex":
        print("I AM SKRILLEX")
        time.sleep(1)

    elif meme == "DAW":
        print("Because I use Reason")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("What software do I use? Read the fucking info mate!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("You ever heard of a de-esser mate?")
        time.sleep(1)
```

.. For a start :)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted to happen! You legend!